# SUMIF function not working is DAX better?

Tags: excel, dax, sumifs

I have a big file with ratio and amounts in column. From this I want to calculate the weighted average of a ratio. However, all the ratios and amounts are in the same column. They are for several years and for each year several scenarios and for each scenario several balance items for several banks. What I want is in a separate new column (on the right) a ratio for one specific year a specific balance sheet item for a specific scenario for all bank.

This is the approach I have taken

I am using the following formulas in excel:

=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,$G$1,D:D,D2)

Let me explain the formula a bit:

Sum everything in column E IF:

- A:A,A2 ; in column A all the bank_code, so for each bank
- B:B,B2 ; in column B the period/year are mentioned, for each year
- C:C,$G$1 : in column C the balance sheet items are mentioned, the specific  balance I am looking for is in cell $G$1
- D:D,D2 ; in column D all the scenarios are mentioned so for each specific scenario

Why am I using the SUMIF function? That is way of filtering things out.
I want to do the same for the amounts in the next column.

After making the two columns I want to use the sumproduct function with a conditional products calculation.

My problem is that for some row the abovementioned SUMIF formula is not working.

Why is that is it not working for some rows and some not?

Recently Just started off with DAX. Is there a better way of doing this? I will be using the end results to upload to Power BI / Tableau or Qlikview.

Does this screen shot help?

[image]

Comment: _My problem is that for some row the abovementioned SUMIF formula is not working_ It means that for some rows criteria are false (i.e. an extra space). You can test it entering for example `=C5=$G$1` in empty cell. _Does this screen shot help?_ There is no screenshot in question.

Comment: @BrakNicku yes there was a link to a sceenshot in the question. Take the time to edit the Q to see these details. First time users can't post images.

Comment: What do you mean with "formula is not working"? Inspect your data and find which criterion does not match.

Comment: "It means that for some rows criteria are false" that was the problem. Thansk for that BrakNicku. Also , thanks to the rest of the people who commented!